# GoogleSignInAccount variable is null in example from Fitness API docs

Tags: android, kotlin, google-authentication, google-fit

I'm trying to follow this [document](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) for accessing the Google Fit History API on my android phone.

I've went through the required steps:
1. Generating a debug key
2. Creating a client ID from the SHA1
3. Installing Google Play Services in SDK tools (Could not find Google Repository)
4.  Using example code from [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history)

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.view.MenuItem

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.os.AsyncTask
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessOptions
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataReadRequest
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import android.util.Log
import kotlin.system.exitProcess


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build()

        val googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)
        if(googleSignInAccount.idToken.isNullOrEmpty()){
            Log.e("GSA",googleSignInAccount.toString())
            exitProcess(1)
        }

        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val now = Date()
        cal.time = now
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1)
        val endTime = cal.timeInMillis

        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -12)
        val startTime = cal.timeInMillis
        val response = Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, googleSignInAccount)
                .readData(DataReadRequest.Builder()
                        .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build())
        AsyncTask.execute(Runnable {
            run(){
                Log.d ("GSA",googleSignInAccount.account.toString())
                val readDataResult = Tasks.await(response)
                val dataSet = readDataResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                println(dataSet.toString())
            }
        })
        ...
    }
```

However, every time I run this, I notice that the `googleSignInAccount` is just the default object and most of the fields are null. This means the call to the Fitness API returns:

```
2019-11-09 14:15:49.933 31216-31263/site.arashout.fitpets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: site.arashout.fitpets, PID: 31216
    java.lang.Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.
...
```

I tried Googling around, but I still don't understand how to properly and easily authenticate.